# App Engine - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using App Engine, SDK 1.6.3 with Python 2.7.

I've created a model like this:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    website = db.StringProperty()
```

I can iterate and see everything except the Key id's.  For example, in the interactive shell I can run this:

```
from models import *
list = MyModel.all()
for p in list:
    print(p.name)
```

and it prints the name of every Entity.  But when I run this:

```
from models import *
list = MyModel.all()
for p in list:
    print(p.key.id)  [or p.key.name or p.key.app]
```

I get an AttributeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py", line 317, in post
    exec(compiled_code, globals())
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Can anyone please help me??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

key() and id() are instance methods.  Try with parenthesis:

```
   for p in list:
        print(p.key().id())
```

See the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key).

Answer (score 1):

[`key()` is a method](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_key) and [`id()` is also a method](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key_id).
So you'd need to do:

```
from models import MyModel
lst = MyModel.all()
for p in lst:
    print(p.key().id())
```

Other notes:

1. Try to avoid, when possible, `from [something] import *`. This can cause difficult-to-debug namespace issues.
2. Don't shadow built-ins with variable names. E.g. `list` should not be used.